Is there a way to isolate a specific installed library into my project and compile it with the rest of a project?
I have multiple python projects and when I compile one of them the using Python to Exe, I end up compiling all the libraries that I have downloaded. I also noticed that in my project, even though I have specified an import, I still have access ,via import, to the other libraries that I do not need for the project.
So this is how I tried to solve my issues
I decided to remap my python projects folder to the hard drive root. But when I went to install the library I wanted I got a bunch of errors directing me to the original library install location
I figure that because the libraries folder is installed further down the folder hierarchy just simply installing the libraries I want wouldn't work. As such I did test this and I got a bunch of errors looking for the folder where Python is actually installed.
In theory, if I install Python into a new folder in the root file of my hard drive, I could create an environment just for programing, separate from the rest of my files. In turn I could isolate downloaded packages into various projects and compile them without unnecessary libraries in my final exe application.
so instead of having one global library for all my projects, I could have multiple of the same library for my various projects.
I do agree that this solution is inefficient but I could not come up with anything else
Note that my OS is Windows 10.

The standard method is the use of virtual environments.

I also personally prefer pyenv-virtualenv, so it manages both the virtual environments and multiple Python interpreters for me, but that may be overkill depending on your needs.
